# Want to print single digit value in txt file using Batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a single digit value in a txt file using Batch script.
Here is my sample code:

```
set no=1
set flag=7

echo FlagStatus=%flag%>>Output.txt
echo[>>Output.txt
echo Number=%no%>>Output.txt
```

But this is not working properly. The line with value 1 prints without value and if I use any value other than 1, it doesn't even prints the line
Here is the output of this code:

```
Number=
```

I am excepting following output:

```
FlagStatus=1

Number=7
```

I will be grateful for your help. thanks

Comment: If you use `echo on`, you will see the debug output of the commands, how they will be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your numbers directly in front of the redirection `>` you give the command to use a specific output stream, instead of stdout.

```
echo FlagStatus=1>>Output.txt
```

is executed as

```
echo FlagStatus=   1>>Output.txt
```

This means, redirect the stdout of the `echo` command to `Output.txt`.
In case of `flag=2` it becomes
redirect the stderr of the `echo` command to `Output.txt`, but echo does output nothing to stderr at all.

A simple solution is to use a block instead, it's faster, more readable and avoids problems with stream handles.

```
set no=1
set flag=7

(
  echo FlagStatus=%flag%
  echo(
  echo Number=%no%
) >>Output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,I have been stuck at this problem for 3 days. It's solved out by your method. Thansk again